# How to properly render the return of AJAX POST MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 and I am trying to send a post request and I am getting a successful return from my controller with the resulting view in HTML form, but I'm not sure what to do with it at that point.

JS

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: submitUrl, type: "POST", traditional: true,
            data: { EventName: 'Name of event'},
            success: function(data){
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEvent(EventModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

So you can see that my controller either returns a View or a RedirectToAction.  In the success callback of my ajax call I am doing the following:  $("#content").html(data);
But nothing seems to happen.  Can someone help push me in the right direction of properly handling the return of the controller action.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should return a JSON example: {"me": "its ok"} in your "success" should parse and display the message.

Comment: You can use the Window.location of javascript for redirect as you are doing in the server side. Return success flag to client and let him choose the path

Comment: Hi John, sorry, but I didn't quite understand your statement.  Should I return Json(View(model)) from my controller and leave my Javascript how it is?  Thanks.

Comment: HI Devesh, I thought about that, but I might need to do server validation on the model and return that "View(model)", so I'd want to see the modified model.

Comment: First you must define what you want to return, you can give an example of what is returned?

Comment: See at the end of the day you are going to server side validation , so do that one the server and if it fails return text like "Error" , in other case just return the view content to ajax call either as text or html or json. You can use the partialView for this job in place of View . My point is that you should handle the logic of redirect also in the client side.

Comment: return Json(new {foo="bar"}); and success -> alert(data.foo);

Comment: @JohnPaulCárdenas - Whether he returns JSON, HTML, Plain Text, XML, or any other format is really irrelevant. We really need to see the HTTP Response to understand why this might be failing.

Comment: Then you can use Chrome, on the Network tab, you can view the status of your REQUEST.

Comment: @user518043 - It would be immensely helpful if you could use Fiddler, or just the Dev tools inside your favorite browser to look at the actual response that comes back from the server. What is the response code, and the body? Can you put a breakpoint on that line and inspect the variable to ensure you are indeed getting back valid HTML.

Comment: @Josh Please see the modified question, I updated it with the response header and body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a Create Event form on your page and you want to send an AJAX request to create a new event. Then you want to replace a section in your page `#content` with the results of the `CreateEvent` action.

It looks like your AJAX is set up correctly so that `CreateEvent` returns a successful response. I think you're now confused about the response. You have several options but let's choose two.

**JSON response**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEvent(EventModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var event = service.CreateEvent(model); // however you create an event
        return Json(event);
    }
    else
    {
        // model is not valid so return to original form
        return View("Index", model);
    }
    ...
```

Now you need to generate html markup from the JSON and insert it into `#content`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: submitUrl, type: "POST", traditional: true,
    data: { EventName: 'Name of event'},
    success: function(data){
        var obj = JSON.Parse(data);
        var html; // build html with the obj containing server result
        $("#content").html(html);
    }
})
```

or **HTML fragment**

Instead of returning a full page with a `Layout` defined we'll return just a `PartialView` without `Layout` and all the `head` and `script` tags.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEvent(EventModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var event = service.CreateEvent(model); // however you create an event
        return PartialView("CreateEventResult", event);
    }
    else
    {
        // model is not valid so return to original form
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

Now make a new partial view *CreateEventResult.cshtml* (Razor)

```
@model Namespace.EventModelResult
@ {
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    <!-- this stuff inserted into #content -->
    @Model.Date
    ...
</div>
```

and the javascript is unchanged

```
$.ajax({
    url: submitUrl, type: "POST", traditional: true,
    data: { EventName: 'Name of event'},
    success: function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    }
})
```

**Edit:**
If your Event creation fails for any reason after you have validated the input, you'll have to decide how you want to respond. One option is to add a response status to the object you return and just display that instead of the newly created Event.

Comment: Jasen, Thank you for extremely helpful breakdown.  Since you are getting me on the right track I have a couple questions.  I am trying to transition from how MVC handles the action result where it just happens.  Meaning, if a model create is successful it will return a new link (sending user to the index of the controller) or a model containing validation errors.  It looks like from your example I will need to know which one I am expecting. Is there a way to handle both, or am I thinking about this all wrong with how AJAX works for posting models?  Thanks again!

Comment: Since you are using AJAX to handle CreateEvent you're not going to leave the original page -- so you just return the result. Are trying to do [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: Jasen, yes that is what I was trying to do.  I was trying to leverage the razor code somehow so that on the return of the ajax call, I could use the exact same code already in place to handle the refresh of the page/redirect/etc.  I see that this isn't possible doing AJAX calls and that I need to do the refresh myself, which might actually be better because now the page doesn't need to be reloaded but I can just replace the html with the new json object returned from the server.  Thanks for your input.